# How to pass metadata in batches to dense neural network concatenated with CNN

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to pass images as well as meta_data. I am confused about how to pass NumPy data with images. Metadata is tabular information of the images.

Here is a dense network for metadata, and vgg_model for images

```
inp = Input(shape=(256,))
y=Dense(64,activation="relu")(inp)
y=Dense(32,activation="relu")(y)

x= cnn_model()
z=concatenate([x,y])
out=Dense(classes,activation='softmax')
```

I created a generator to output meta_data in batches
from tensorflow.keras import utils

```
class metaGenerator(utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, meta_data , batch_size=20):
        self.meta=meta_data
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.on_epoch_end()

def __len__(self):
    return int(np.floor(len(self.meta) / self.batch_size))

def __getitem__(self, index):
    indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
    list_IDs_temp = [self.meta[k] for k in indexes]
    X,_= self.data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

    return X

def on_epoch_end(self):
    self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.meta))


def data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
    X=[]
    for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
      X.append(self.meta[ID])
    return np.array(X)
```

Here I created a function to combine output of both

```
def dual_datagen(df,clinical_features):
    eff_generator=data_gen.flow_from_dataframe(df,directory='/content/data',
                                               target_size=(img_shape,img_shape),
                                               x_col='img_id',
                                               y_col=col,
                                               class_mode='raw',
                                               shuffle=True,
                                               batch_size=batch_size)


    while True:
        x_1 = eff_generator.next()
        x_2 = metaGenerator(clinical_features,20)

        yield [x_1[0], x_2[0]], x_1[1]
```

I am not sure, whether it's correct or not

When I try to train it. It throws an error

```
train_gen =dual_datagen(df,clinical_features)
model.fit(train_gen,epochs=2)
```

I got following error

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

**EDIT**

I updated the code a bit

```
from tensorflow.keras import utils
class metaGenerator(utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, meta_data , batch_size=20):
        self.meta=meta_data
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.floor(len(self.meta) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
        list_IDs_temp = indexes
        X= self.data_generation(list_IDs_temp)
        return X

    def on_epoch_end(self):

        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.meta))

    def data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
      X=np.take(self.meta,list_IDs_temp,axis=0)
      return X
```

The issue I realized is that , `x_2 = metaGenerator(clinical_features,20)` is generating `<__main__.metaGenerator object at 0x7f16d1e206a0>` instead of array

Comment: What do you mean by 'metadata'? What kind of information would you like to pass as input? How do you handle it to your model? Please provide more information

Comment: It's look like you want something where you can feed image and some data regarding that too as inputs.The  first code that you have mentioned is definitely not the right way to do it,you need two model side by side and then and you need to concatenate them before final output layer